# Defining stochastic differential equation & simulating a system of three SDEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random

I am no expert on SDE but I've been messing around with MMA's built in functions and it makes it quite easy to do some simple simulations. I bumped into this system of equations (below) in a paper and was trying to tweak the documentation center equations to simulate it.

It describes biological growth of biomass $X$, in a reactor that is fed substrate $S$, and the growth of bacteria is defined by $(dX)_g$

$$(dX)_g= \mu S/(K_j+S) *Xdt+\sigma dW,$$

$$dX=(dX)_g-Q_eXdt+(Q_rX_r-Q_oX)dt+\sigma_i dW$$

$$dS=-1/Y (dX)_g+Q_f(S_f-S)dt+\sigma_j dW $$

And $W, W_i, W_j$ are Wiener processes, $\sigma$s are volatility and $\mu$ is defined as the specific growth rate but represents drift.

Where the coefficients: $S_f, X_r, Y, Q_o,Q_f,Q_r,Q_e$ are scalars and constants (I can provide what they stand for is requested).

My *approach was to* define $(dX)_g$ first, simulate it and call it in the equations for $dX$ and $dS$:
     Qe = 10; Qr = 10; Xr = 30; Qo = 10; [Sigma] = 10; [Sigma]2 = 20; [Mu] = 0.25; Y = 0.25; Qf = 10; Sf = 300; Ks = 200;

```
a = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]xg[t] == \[Mu]*s[t]/(Ks + s[t])*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], xg[t], {xg, 25}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
aproc = RandomFunction[%, {0., 5., 0.01}]
```

And then call the function `aproc` I defined above in the two equations for $dX$ and $dS$:

```
b = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]s[t] == -1/Y (\[Mu]*s[t]/(Ks + s[t])*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t]) +Qf (Sf - s[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], {s[t], x[t]}, {s, 200}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
bproc = RandomFunction[%, {0., 5., 0.01}];
c = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == (\[Mu]*s[t]/(Ks + s[t])*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t]) - Qe*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t +(Qr*Xr - Qo*x[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], {x[t],s[t]}, {x, 100}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
cproc = RandomFunction[%, {0., 5., 0.01}];
```

but I need to add the $(dX)_g$ into the equation before `Qe*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t`
I tried defining its SDE separately and simulating it with `RandomFunction` then inserting it into the $dX$ equation above and clearly saw that's not the way to do this...

So my question is: How do I write the system of SDE above? And perhaps shed some insight as to whether the `ItoProcess` is what I want to use?

Comment: Please ALWAYS provide a COMPLETE code sample! Don't expect others to make up their own set of parameters if they want to help with your question!

Comment: Also, what's wrong with directly substituting $(dX)_g$ into the other two equations? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thanks @sebhofer.

My mistake was trying to simulate `ItoProcess` with `RandomFunction` and then calling it into another `ItoProcess` simulation... But the SDE simulations don't work that way. Instead I used the `ItoProcess` function for a vector process $x[t], s[t]$; inserted $(dW)_g$ directly into the equations and ended up with a 2-equation system of SDEs:

```
Qe = 10; Qr = 10; Xr = 30; Qo = 10; σ = 10; σ2 = 20; μ = 0.25; Y = 0.25; Qf = 10; Sf = 300; Ks = 200;

proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == (μ s[t]/(Ks + s[t]) x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + σ \[DifferentialD]w1[t]) - Qe x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + (Qr*Xr -Qo*x[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + σ2 \[DifferentialD]w1[t], \[DifferentialD]s[t] == -1/Y (μ s[t]/(Ks + s[t]) x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + σ \[DifferentialD]w2[t]) + Qf (Sf - s[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + σ2 \[DifferentialD]w2[t]},
{x[t], s[t]}, {{x, s}, {25, 800}}, t, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}];
RandomFunction[%, {0., 5., 0.001}];
ListLinePlot[%, PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "s[t]"}]
```

This simulates both equations and then I can plot using `ListLinePlot[%]`

Comment: Good you figured it out, but you still haven't posted a sensible set of values, neither in the question nor in your answer!

Comment: @ sebhofer How come when I try to simulate 20 paths with `RandomFunction[%,{0,5,0.01},20]`, I see `TemporalData` be generated by nothing appears when I try to plot it with `ListLinePlot[%]` ?

Comment: If we set `sample = RandomFunction[%, {0., 5., 0.001}];` then `sample["ValueDimensions"]` will return 2, hence `ListLinePlot[%]` above returns nothing. Try `ListLinePlot[{sample["PathComponent", 1], sample["PathComponent", 2]},
  PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "s[t]"}]`

Comment: Yeah, this is not quite obvious. You should look at the `TemporalData` documentation for all the options. You can select one of the sampled trajectories by doing something like `rf=RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.001}, 20]; rf["Path", 1]`, which will give you a `List` of raw data. Note, however, that this is not in the correct format to use with `ListPlot` directly. So this solution is rather clunky and @Gosia's solution is probably better!

Comment: I just realized that @Gosia's solution does not work for me. You can do `rf=RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.001},20]; Show[ListPlot[rf["PathComponent", 1]],
 ListPlot[rf["PathComponent", 2]], PlotRange -> All]` though.

Comment: @sebhofer Yup. Exactly what I realized and how I was using it. And for those others browsing in the future, using `PlotRange->All` was critical to visualize both plots, else it would just show the first as we expect from `Show`. Thanks guys @Gosie